# How to two way bind two elements to one date model

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

I have two elements of date picker, one for months and one for years, I want to set two way binding between them and a javascript Date object, my question is as follows:

Is it possible to do so? and if so how? 
If not how can I emulate this behavior at least?

Code example:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" required [(ngModel)]="exp.StartDate.Month" >
   <option *ngFor="let obj of months" [value]="obj">{{obj}}</option>>
</select>


<select class="selectpicker form-control" required [(ngModel)]="exp.StartDate.Year">
   <option *ngFor="let obj of years" [value]="obj">{{obj}}</option>>
</select>
```

Both selectors get their data in the form of arrays with either years or months (0-11).

Comment: There should be no problem as long as the datepickers do not replace the date object with a completely new one. If they only modify the date object in place when you change the values it should just work.

Comment: let me just see if I understand: if I use ngModelChange on both to update the single date object it should be fine?  and  they are not date pickers, just dropdown lists with month/year data.

Comment: What I meant is that if you bind the whole date object to whatever pickers you have, and if they update the object by replacing it with a new one then you will have a problem. However, if your pickers internally change the date object by modifying it (e.g. date_object.setTime(1332403882588)) then you should be fine. However, it would be easier to help if you posted some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to have a property fecha with setter. So in your Component you have

```
year:number;
month:number;
get fecha():any
{
    return new Date(this.year,this.month-1,1)
}
console.log(year,month,fecha);
```

If you have ngModel, you can split the [(ngModel)]

```
<select [value] = "exp.StartDate.Month" (input)="updateMonth($event.target.value)" >
...
</select>
<select [value] = "exp.StartDate.Year" (input)="updateYear($event.target.value)">

//In your component
updateMonth(month:number)
  {
    this.exp.StartDate.Month=month;
    this.exp.StartDate.Value=this.exp.StartDate.Year+'-'+this.exp.StartDate.Mont+'-1';
  }
  updateYear(year:number)
  {
    this.exp.StartDate.Year=year;
    this.exp.StartDate.Value=this.exp.StartDate.Year+'-'+this.exp.StartDate.Mont+'-1';
  }
```

Or you can create a custom form control to control the value. I don't know if your exp.StartDate is or not a javascript Date. I write a code with a custom form control that expect a javaScript Date Object (if you use a String try to change the code)

```
import { Component, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

//Really TODO change input to select
@Component({
  selector: 'app-month-year',
  template: `
    <input [disabled]="disabled" [value] = "month" (input)="updateMonth($event.target.value)" >
    <input [disabled]="disabled" [value] = "year" (input)="updateYear($event.target.value)">
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MonthYearComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MonthYearComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  month:number;
  year:number;


  // Allow the input to be disabled, and when it is make it somewhat transparent.
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input('value') value;

  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  updateMonth(month:number)
  {
    this.month=month;
    this.value=this.getDate(); //<--change the "value"
    this.onChange(this.value);
  }
  updateYear(year:number)
  {
    this.year=year;
    this.value=this.getDate(); //change the value
    this.onChange(this.value);

  }

  constructor() { }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) { 
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) { //<--when receive a value
    if (value) {
      this.month=value.getMonth()+1;
      this.year=value.getFullYear();

      }

  }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  //It's better use a function to return the value
  private getDate() 
  {
    const date=new Date();
    date.setFullYear(this.year,this.month-1,1);
    return date;
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I apply this via ngModel? that's exactly what I'm looking for.